# Natural join subset decomposition

Tags: database, join, relational-database, database-schema, natural-join

For this question , I found the answer is (c). but I can give an example to show that (c) is not correct. which is the answer?

Let r be a relation instance with schema R = (A, B, C, D). We define `r1 = ‘select A,B,C from r`’ and `r2 = ‘select A, D from r`’. Let `s = r1 * r2` where * denotes natural join. Given that the decomposition of r into r1 and r2 is lossy, which one of the following is true?

(a) s is subset of r
(b) r U s = r
(c) r is a subset of s
(d) r *  s = s

If the Answer is (c) , consider the following example with lossy decomposition of r into r1 and r2.

Table r

### A      B      C      D

1     10     100    1000
 2     20     200    1000
 3     20     200    1001

Table r1

### A      B      C

1     10     100 
 2     20     200

Table r2

### A     D

2    1000
 3    1001

Table s (natural join of r1 and r2)

### A      B      C      D

2     20     200    1000

The answer is not (c) . but I can also give you an example that (c) can  be an answer.
What should be the answer?

Comment: if you can give an example of c been right why wouldn't you post it?

Comment: yes of course. just click on this link       http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-management-systems-set-10/

Comment: Learn the *definitions* of "decomposition" and "lossy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table r is:

```
A B  C   D
1 10 100 1000
2 20 200 1000
3 20 200 1001
```

r1 is:

```
r1 = ‘select A,B,C from r’ 

A B  C   
1 10 100 
2 20 200 
3 20 200
```

r2 is:

```
r2 = ‘select A, D from r'

A D
1 1000
2 1000
3 1001
```

s is:

```
s = r1 * r2

1 10 100 1000
2 20 200 1000
3 20 200 1001
```

So effectively r is as subset of s. If the definicion of r1 is ‘select A,B,C from r’ you just can't remove a row (as you did in your example) from the result and said that r1 still complies with the definition, the same applies to r2 where you remove the first row.

Comment: Yeah, but this is different question, see I have mentioned that the "decomposition of r into r1 and r2 is lossy" so loss can occur.

Comment: @MehulJain is lossy because, as a result of the query, you're not taking all the columns values, lossy doesn't mean erase a row from the result.

Comment: Okay I'm getting little bit but sorry, I didn't really get the "lossy" concept. Can you explain that why the example that you gave is lossy??

Comment: @MehulJain because the query results on r1 and r2 does not bring back all the data on the rows you "lose" some information. if the original data contains columns ABCD and the result is AD the you don't have BC, which is lossy not because you lost the data, just because it isn't on the query result.

Comment: @MehulJain if I answered your question you should mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

Table r
A B C D

1 10 100 1000
1 20 200 2000

Table r1
A B C

1 10 100
1 20 200

Table r2
A D

1 1000
1 2000

Table s (natural join of r1 and r2)
A B C D

1 10 100 1000
1 20 200 1000
1 10 100 2000
1 20 200 2000

The decomposition is called "lossy" because we have lost the ability to recompose the original relation value using natural join.  This lost ability manifests itself by extra rows appearing when we try the natural join.  The underlying cause why this happens is that the decomposition did not retain any key ( { {B} {C} {D} } ) fully in both tables of the decomposition.  If any key of the original is fully retained in all components of a decomposition, then the decomposition isn't lossy.